# Subsonic 3: Strongly typed return value for stored procedures that return mixed results from different tables

Tags: stored-procedures, subsonic3

Say I have a stored procedure that returns dataSet from 2 different tables. Example:

```
SELECT Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName, SUM(Sales.SaleAmount) AS SalesPerCustomer
FROM Customers LEFT JOIN Sales
ON Customers.CustomerID = Sales.CustomerID
GROUP BY Customers.FirstName, Customers.LastName
```

Is there any way to get a strongly typed list as a result from this stored procedure ? Something like this:

```
StoredProcedure sp = myDevDB.GetCustomerSales();

List<MyCustomType> resultSet = sp.ExecuteTypedList<MyCustomType>();
```

How and where do I define the MyCustomType class ? How do I map its properties to the actual table columns ?

Thanks,
Zohrab.

Answer (score 3):

I just created a asp.net web page that does this. Try this:

```
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    SqlDataAdapter adtp = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
    adtp.Fill(ds);
    StringBuilder b = new StringBuilder();

    b.AppendLine("class " + this.txtSP.Text + "_QueryResult");
    b.AppendLine("{");  

    foreach ( DataColumn c in ds.Tables[0].Columns )
    {
        b.AppendLine(string.Format("property {0} {1}  {{ get; set; }}", c.DataType, c.ColumnName));
    }
    b.AppendLine("}" + Environment.NewLine);

    this.txtResult.Text = b.ToString();
}
catch { }
```